# flutter sliver list tabbar bottom overflowed error

Tags: flutter, tabbar, flutter-sliver

I am a newbie of flutter.
I have just started to rebuild my android app built by Kotlin to flutter.

However, I am stuck in building the user page.
I intended to build the page like this screenshot
[image: img]

However, I continuously get bottom overflowed error.
How can I solve this problem?

I am looking forward to your help.

I will attach the whole code of the page.

```
import 'package:botanic_flutter/login_page.dart';
import 'package:botanic_flutter/main.dart';
import 'package:botanic_flutter/root_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:botanic_flutter/custom_color_scheme.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';


class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userUid;

  AccountPage(this.userUid);

  @override
  _AccountPageState createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _Auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  FirebaseUser _currentUser;

  TabController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) {
            return <Widget> [
              SliverList(
//                itemExtent: 300,
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                  Container(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _detailedBody()
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TabBar(
                unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.greyColor,
                labelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                controller: _controller,
                indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                tabs: [
                  Container(
                    height: 90,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Tab(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.home,
                      ),
                      text: 'PLANTS',
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 90,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Tab(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_border,
                      ),
                      text: 'BOOKMARK',
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: TabBarView(
                  controller: _controller,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.clear_all,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3*1.4,
                                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                                    isExpanded: true,
                                    items: <String>['Foo', 'Bar'].map((String value) {
                                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                        value: value,
                                        child: Text(value),
                                      );
                                    }).toList(),
                                    onChanged: (_) {},
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.mode_edit,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 1.0),
                                  child: Icon(
                                    Icons.delete,
                                    color: Colors.grey,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 30,
                                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4.5,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                                          offset: Offset(2, 4),
                                          blurRadius: 5,
                                          spreadRadius: 2)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  child: FlatButton(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "+식물등록",
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 13,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () => {
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            child: GridView.builder(
                              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                                  childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                                  mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                                  crossAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                              itemCount: notes.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                                child: Image.network(notes[index],
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                        itemCount: notes.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                          child: Image.network(notes[index],
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _detailedBody() {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 3 / 4,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                image: NetworkImage(
                    'http://www.korea.kr/newsWeb/resources/attaches/2017.08/03/3737_cp.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -41.0, 0.0),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 90.0,
                      height: 90.0,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,

                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 82.0,
                      height: 82.0,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://steemitimages.com/DQmS1gGYmG3vL6PKh46A2r6MHxieVETW7kQ9QLo7tdV5FV2/IMG_1426.JPG')
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                        width: 90.0,
                        height: 90.0,
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 28.0,
                              height: 28.0,
                              child: FloatingActionButton(
                                onPressed: null,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                //child: Icon(Icons.add),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 25.0,
                              height: 25.0,
                              child: FloatingActionButton(
                                onPressed: null,
                                backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                                child: Icon(Icons.add),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                Text(
                  'nickname',
                  style:
                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24.0),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                Text(
                  'introduce',
                  style:
                  TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0)),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    signOutWithGoogle().then((_) {
                      Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));

                    });
                  },
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                  child: Text('로그아웃'),

                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0)),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '0',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '식물수',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '0',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '팔로워',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          '0',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '팔로잉',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),

    );
  }
  List<String> notes = [
    'https://steemitimages.com/DQmS1gGYmG3vL6PKh46A2r6MHxieVETW7kQ9QLo7tdV5FV2/IMG_1426.JPG',
    'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/BKvyuWq6b5apNOqvSw3VxB-QhezYHAoX1AptJdWPl-Ktq-Efm2gotbeXFtFlkr_ZPZmpEHc2BsKTC9oFQgzBimKsf5oRtTqOGdlO3MTfwiOT54E5m-lCtt6ANOMzmhNsYMGRp9Pg1NzjwMRUWNoWX0oJEFcnFvjOj2Rr4LtZpkXyiQFO',
    'https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R720x0.q80/?scode=mtistory2&fname=http%3A%2F%2Fcfile28.uf.tistory.com%2Fimage%2F2343174F58DBC14C2ECB8B',
  ];
  Future<void> signOutWithGoogle() async {
    // Sign out with firebase
    await _Auth.signOut();
    // Sign out with google
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  }

}
```

Comment: i think for your `Widget _detailedBody() {` you can return a `SingleCHildScrollView` to clear the error

Comment: @Ggriffo Thank you for your comment. Although I changed my codes, it has still overflowed error.

Comment: If it persists a quick fix is to wrap your whole body in a SingleChildScrollView .

Comment: Having in mind there are wide range of device displays out there... Better to be safe .. although in your production/release app you won't see the overflow errors

Comment: I have wrapped my whole body as the SingleChildScrollView, but I gained the following error: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderNestedScrollViewViewport#e13c1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1687 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: you are supposed to wrap the body inside the `NestedScrollView` not the scaffold one.

Comment: Thank you so much! after wrapping the body as `SizedBox`, I wrapped the `SingleChildScrollView `. the overflowed error is solved!! but the `SliverList` part scroll and body part scroll separately work.. <= this problem has been solved adding scrollcontroller in the `NestedScrollView` and the `SingleChildScrollView`. I deeply appreciate your help!!